Determinant of Symmetrized Seifert Matrix
Exercice 3.4 of Livingston's Knot Theory: For a Seifert matrix $V$, $\text{det}(V+V^t) \neq 0.$ (Why?)
I know that $V-V^t$ will return the intersection form of the Seifert surface, which is unimodular. But I have no idea how to adapt such an argument to work for $V+V^t.$ Does the stronger proposition that $V+V^t$ is unimodular hold? All comments are greatly appreciated! This question is not related to any courses I am taking, it is just coming from my independent studies.

Working mod $2$ you can see that the determinants have the same parity (i.e. are both odd.)
